# How is it that "both a man and a picture are animals"?

Tags: aristotle

I just began reading Aristotle's *Categories*, and stumbled on the second sentence: a man and a picture are not animals; while a man is an animal, a picture is not, even a picture of a man. In one commentary, this was explained away as the picture in question being of a man, and made it seem as if a child were being asked by a teacher to point to an animal in the room (e.g. the teacher), and then to an animal in a picture book. However, if this is implied, I don't see how, as the commentator seems to be reading into the text an interpretation, rather than drawing it out from textual evidence. To my eye, the sentence itself just looks strange; I can't see deeper into it, as I don't see why Aristotle would choose such a strange example (why not just use the example of two people with the same name, or homonymous words like 'felt'?). When my little sister used to ask me what something meant, I would come up with some reasonable-sounding bullshit; I'd rather not be taken in the same way. What is a good exegetical paraphrase of this sentence?

Comment: "*Thus, for example, both a man and a picture are animals. These have only a name in common and the definition of being which corresponds to the name is different; for if one is to say what being an animal is for each of them, one will give two distinct definitions.*" It seems pretty straightforward without any reading in. X "being an animal" would need to be defined differently to make it true of each of them.

Comment: It isn't straightforward to me, and I get twisted up in "a man and a picture are animals". I could read 'picture' as "picture of some animal", but even then it doesn't feel natural on my tongue to say, "The picture [of this duck] is an animal". I would feel compelled to say, "The picture [of this duck] is *of* an animal". Is it natural in Attic Greek to say a sentence like the former?

Comment: He is making a philosophical point, what difference does it make what is or is not "natural" to say in some particular language?

Comment: In English, "The picture is an animal" is always false; "The picture is of an animal" is sometimes true. "The difference" is an implicitly ontological one. It seems important to my eye whether or not Aristotle believed that "The picture is an animal" can sometimes be said and not be absurd, and if so why.

Comment: If it depends on linguistic minutiae there is nothing ontological about it, you are getting bogged down in inconsequential surface grammar. And people often say "this is a lion" pointing at a painting or a statue even in English. If you want to know what Aristotle believed ontologically look elsewhere, like Metaphysics.

Comment: Yes, people do often point and say, "This is X [animal]" - but that is different from saying, "This picture is an animal". I think of them as answers to different questions, the first being, "What is this figure depicting?", the latter being, "What kind of thing is this picture?". For a picture to literally be thought of as an animal (as opposed to what it is a picture of), you have to believe in something strange, and I want to know if Aristotle did so, and the Greeks in general. Or is this just an infelicity in translation?

Comment: For a picture of X to be *called* X all you need is a definitional convention about "is X", which is exactly Aristotle's point. You do not have to believe anything in particular, and with ontological "being X" it will have "only a name in common". Things are not being "literally thought of" according to uses of a copula, they are very opportunistic and promiscuous in most languages, including ancient Greek and English.

Comment: "Cupola"? "Definitional convention"? I don't know the history of linguistics well enough, but what you wrote looks suspiciously like an anachronism you might be reading into Aristotle. I don't disagree that 'is' can be "very opportunistic and promiscuous", certainly in English, probably in ancient Greek, too. The question, then: how do you know that Aristotle is not saying something strange, akin to some Platonist order of being, where a picture of an animal *is* an animal, but rather is speaking a bit imprecisely, meaning "a picture *of* an animal"? To my eye, the text itself seems ambiguous.

Comment: My own reading of most pre-contemporary philosophers is that there was widespread confusion, though of varying depths, about linguistics and metaphysics. Was Aristotle free of this? I have only begun re-reading Aristotle again after 15 years, but I don't recall him being free of this confusion. A good exegetical paraphrase, to my eye, must be sensitive to his beliefs on these things.

Comment: Because he says (in translation) "*the definition of being which corresponds to the name is different*", and "copula" is just a neutral name for analogs of "being". Aristotle did have peculiar views about images (*phantasma*), for example, [he wrote in *De Anima*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-psychology/suppl4.html) that “*whenever one contemplates, one necessarily at the same time contemplates in images*”. But how does that alter his definitional point in *Categories*? And how "speaking a bit imprecisely" is not itself an anachronism based on modern idea of "precision"?

Comment: I'll have to finish _Categories_, as well as the [SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/), to feel more confident about this, but my sense is that my confusion came from not reading "definition of being" in a categorical way. That is, a man belong to one category called 'animal'; a picture belongs to another - albeit different - category, also called 'animal'; they are homonymous because both the man and the picture belong to categories that share a name, but yet are different. I have a niggling intuition re: "definition of being", but this feels like an answer.

Comment: The exegetical paraphrase would then be something like, "[b]oth a man and a picture are animals [because the man belong to one category called 'animal', the picture belongs to another category also called 'animal', as two people can have the same name, and thus both the man and the picture are animals, as John Kennedy and John Lennon are both Johns]".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the text of the definition of ‘homonym’, and contrasting it to the definition of ‘synonym’, my sense is that the homonymous term in question is ‘animal’. The paraphrase would then be: “A man and a picture [of some animal] are both animals; but because the man is a species of the genus ‘living animal’, while the picture is a species of the genus ‘pictured animal’, they are merely homonymous, as the abbreviated term ‘animal’ refers to two different kinds of groups". I am not happy with this, as I have to read into the text the bracketed adjective. Also, I am coming at this post-Frege, with a Platonic distinction between sense and reference, and I suspect - if can't speak to - some anachronism in my interpretation.

Comment: Aristotle spoke at length about 'mimesus'. By mentioning the picture, in Categories, he may be referring to the picture being an 'imitation'. Don't know if that makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesMSaunders! Reading about Aristotle's views on mimesis would go a long way to solving, or at least making clear, some of the difficulties I encountered in my conversation above with @Conifold.

Answer (score 1):

This just seems to be confusion about literal and idiomatic use of language. A tiger is an animal. A photograph of a tiger is literally a photograph, not an animal. Idiomatically, one might say of the photograph 'Look, a tiger!'. There is a distinction between a picture and an object it depicts, a distinction that can be blurred or overlooked altogether in everyday language.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started reading Aristotle (the 2 vol complete works in the Bollingen Series by Princeton), and this is the second sentence of the 1st volume. I am completely confused and it seems like an ominous omen for me to keep going...
I found this stack and read the discussions, but unfortunately none of them seems satisfying.
I checked [the Japanese translation online](http://hgonzaemon.g1.xrea.com/Categoriae.html) and luckily it gives Aristotle's original Greek and a brief annotation on this particular one sentence.

Thanks to the Japanese translator's annotation, from what I can make of the original (since my Greek is very limited), the problems lies in the lack of linguistic understanding. The translator obviously think readers have some understanding of Greek and therefore chose the most literal translation without any explanation.
The word that causes problem here is ζῷον. In Greek it has 2 meanings:

> 1.animal;
> 2.image.

So what Aristotle is trying to say here is actually very simple and straightforward. It's like saying in English both "a land alongside a river" and "a savings and loan" are "a bank", no problem with that.

A better (and easier to understand) rendition could be as follows:

> "When things have only a name in common and the definition of being
> which corresponds to the name is different, they are called
> homonymous. Thus, e.g. both a man and a picture are ζῷον... for if one
> is to say what being a ζῷον is for each of them, one will give 2
> distinct definitions."

Answer (score 0):

Two things are said to be homonymous if their name and the account of their essence are different. A man and a painted animal are both "animals" in name, BUT the account of their being animals is different. For example, a man and a portrait of a man are called "man" and share that name, but their essence or being "man" are different.

Two things are said to be synonymous if their name and the account of their essence is the same. A man and an ox are both "animals" in name, AND the account of their being animals is also the same. Both man and ox belong to the species or genus "animal."